# Google App Engine: Retrieving images from the datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blob

I have images stored in the Google app engine datastore. I want to retrieve them and display them in my application. Here's the code for my application:

main.py

```
class FileUpload(Handler):
    def post(self):
        file_upload = self.request.POST.get("file", None)
        file_name = file_upload.filename
        image = Images(id=file_name, file_name=file_name, blob=file_upload.file.read())
        image.put()

        self.response.headers[b'Content-Type'] = mimetypes.guess_type(image.file_name)[0]
        self.response.write(image.blob)

class ImgServe(Handler):
    def get(self, resource):
        image = ndb.Key('Images', resource).get()
        self.response.headers[b'Content-Type'] = mimetypes.guess_type(image.file_name)[0]
        self.response.write(image.blob)            

class Blob(Handler):
    def get(self):
        self.render("blob.html")

class Template(Handler):
    def get(self):
        self.render('template.html')


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage),
                                ('/signup', Register),
                                ('/login', Login),
                                ('/logout', Logout),
                                ('/mp', MP),
                                (r'/file_upload', FileUpload),
                                ('/blob', Blob),
                                (r'/img_serve/<resource:(.*)>', ImgServe),
                                ('/template', Template)], debug=True)
```

blob.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Image Upload</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="/file_upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <div><input type="file" name="file"/></div>
    <div><input type="submit" value="Upload"></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

template.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Template</title>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="/img_serve/evs.jpeg" /> 
</body>
</html>
```

Here's a screenshot of my database:

[image]

However, this is the output that I get on template.html :

[image]

I was expecting 'evs.jpeg' to be displayed on template.html. What seems to be the problem with my code?

Answer (score 0):

You are not obligated to serve images yourself. Google can do the job for you:

See: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/functions

get_serving_url(blob_key, size=None, crop=False, secure_url=None)

You just have have to pass the blob_key you have stored, and you can get the serving url for use in your HTML templates.

*Alternatively, you can follow the doc for serve blob:*

See here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/#Python_Complete_sample_application

```
class ServeHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler):
  def get(self, resource):
    resource = str(urllib.unquote(resource))
    blob_info = blobstore.BlobInfo.get(resource)
    self.send_blob(blob_info)
```

It is also possible to overwrite the filename by passing in a string:

```
self.send_blob(blob_info,save_as='evs.jpg')
```